# VBA code to look if value of cells in sheet 2 column have match in sheet 1 and if so copy cell from sheet 2

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and have a problem that i am trying to solve. I have a sheet      that i call static data (Sheet1). it has customer name , customer ID and column identifying use cases. My flex data (Sheet2) had customer ID, use case and status. I am trying to come up with VBA code that would copy the status for each customer into the corresponding use case column / cell. Any data in Sheet2 that can't be matched with a customer in Sheet 1 should be copied to a separate sheet
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Below are how the sheets are assembled

Sheet 1 Static data

```
Customer Name | Customer ID | Case 1 | Case 2 | Case 3 | Case 4 | Case 5
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Customer A    | 111         |        |        |        |        |
Customer B    | 222         |        |        |        |        |
Customer C    | 333         |        |        |        |        |
Customer D    | 444         |        |        |        |        |
Customer E    | 555         |        |        |        |        |
```

Sheet 2 Flex data

```
Customer ID  | Use Case | Status
---------------------------------
111          |Case 1    | Forecast
222          |Case 1    | Upside
111          |Case 2    | Upside
333          |Case 3    | Pipeline
444          |Case 4    | Pipeline
222          |Case 4    | Forecast
666          |Case 5    | Pipeline
```

Output sheet or Sheet 1

```
Customer Name | Customer ID | Case 1 | Case 2 | Case 3 | Case 4 | Case 5
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Customer A    | 111         |Forecast|Upside  |        |        |
Customer B    | 222         |Upside  |        |        |Forecast|
Customer C    | 333         |        |        |Pipeline|        |
Customer D    | 444         |        |        |        |Pipeline|
Customer E    | 555         |        |        |        |        |
```

Comment: Where is your code you attempted?

Comment: I tried it with VLOOKUP and IF statements

Comment: Do you need VBA? I posted a formula solution, does that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK lets see if we can get this done with VBA.
Here is a potential solution with VBA. This is quick and dirty but it gets the job done. This depends on a sheet1 and a Sheet2.

```
Sub MatchCustomersToCase()

Dim lookUpValue

'step 1 select sheet 1 the spreadsheet.
 Sheet1.Select

'step 2 loop customer id

For I = 1 To 12

Set workingcell = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(I, 2)
lookUpValue = workingcell.Value
cellAddress = workingcell.Address()

'select sheet 2
Sheet2.Select

'find the value in sheet 2
 Call Find_value_in_sheet2(lookUpValue, cellAddress)


Next
End Sub



Sub Find_value_in_sheet2(somevalue, fromAddress)
    Dim FindString As String
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim caseType As String
    Dim CaseValue As String
    Dim listOfValues As Variant

    listOfValues = Array(somevalue)

    If Trim(somevalue) <> "" Then
        With Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A")

            For I = LBound(listOfValues) To UBound(listOfValues)

            Set Rng = .Find(What:=listOfValues(I), _
                            After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                            MatchCase:=False)
            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
             FirstAddress = Rng.Address
           Do

                Application.Goto Rng, True

                caseType = Rng.Offset(0, 1).Value

                If Trim(caseType) = "Case 1" Then
                    CaseValue = Rng.Offset(0, 2).Value
                    Sheet1.Range(fromAddress).Offset(0, 1).Value = CaseValue

                ElseIf Trim(caseType) = "Case 2" Then
                CaseValue = Rng.Offset(0, 2).Value
                    Sheet1.Range(fromAddress).Offset(0, 2).Value = CaseValue

                 ElseIf Trim(caseType) = "Case 3" Then
                CaseValue = Rng.Offset(0, 2).Value
                    Sheet1.Range(fromAddress).Offset(0, 3).Value = CaseValue

                ElseIf Trim(caseType) = "Case 4" Then

                CaseValue = Rng.Offset(0, 2).Value
                    Sheet1.Range(fromAddress).Offset(0, 4).Value = CaseValue

                ElseIf Trim(caseType) = "Case 5" Then

                CaseValue = Rng.Offset(0, 2).Value
                    Sheet1.Range(fromAddress).Offset(0, 5).Value = CaseValue

                End If

             Set Rng = .FindNext(Rng)
             Loop While Not Rng Is Nothing And Rng.Address <> FirstAddress
              End If
            Next I
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Miguel,that looks very promising but it only works if if customer ID is listed only once in sheet 2, I have customer IDs with multiple use cases and i only get one use case copied. Any suggestions. BTW some of the Variables are not defined in the code above.

Comment: @UL1969 oops I see that now, give ma second I will update

Answer (score 1):

You can use a multi-criteria Index/Match:

`=Index([Status Range],Match([customer ID]&[Case No.],[customer ID Range]&[Case No. Range],0)`

entered as an array formula, with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd>

Then, finally wrap around `=IfError([index/match],"")` to hide anything.

Make sure to anchor the references, as in my example:
[image]

So you'll just refer to data on a separate page, I just put it on the same to make it easier to show.

Comment: Bruce, thank you for the information you provided but it is not working for me. I setup my sheet the same way as you are showing and enter the same formula and i don't see cell C2 changing to Forecast. Any hint you can provided? here is my formula  =IFERROR(INDEX($K$2:$K$10,MATCH($B2&C$1,$I$2:$I$10&$J$2:$J$10,0)),"")

Comment: @UL1969 - Do you get an error? Or does it not return the expected value? (Take out `Iferror` until you get the formula working)

Comment: No error, not returning the expected value. If i take out IFERROR i am getting #VALUE!

Comment: @UL1969 - Are you using `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` to enter the formula (instead of just hitting `ENTER`)? Make sure that the Case names and customer IDs are exactly the same in the table, and your lookup table. If you have, for example `Case 1` in `C1`, and `Case 1    ` (note the spaces) in `J2`, it won't match properly.

Comment: It works now after i copied the Case name, is there any way i can copy the formula to the other cells without going to edit each cells formula?

Comment: @UL1969 - If you properly anchored the values, and it looks like you did, you should just have to drag the formula over and down. It should all update automatically.

Comment: It only corrects the formulas after i drag, select formula in cell and than CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER for each single cell

Comment: @UL1969 - Really? After doing `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` originally, if you drag it, it gives you the error, until you manually enter a cell?  That sounds odd, it doesn't do that for me. Is Calculation set to automatic in Excel?

Answer (score 0):

you could try this:

```
Sub main()
    Dim cell1 As Range, cell2 As Range, flexRng As Range, filteredRng As Range, headersRng As Range

    With Worksheets("Sheet 2")
        Set flexRng = .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    End With

    With Worksheets("Sheet 1")
        Set headersRng = .Range("A1", .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
        For Each cell1 In .Range("B2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
            If GetFilteredRange(flexRng, cell1.Value, filteredRng) Then
                For Each cell2 In filteredRng
                    .Cells(cell1.Row, headersRng.Find(what:=cell2.Offset(, 1).Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole).Column).Value = cell2.Offset(, 2)
                Next
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub

Function GetFilteredRange(rangeToFilter As Range, filterValue As Variant, filteredRange As Range) As Boolean
    With rangeToFilter
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=filterValue
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then
            GetFilteredRange = True
            Set filteredRange = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        End If
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help

Comment: You are welcome. If this answer solves your question then please mark it as accepted. Thank you!

Comment: Is there any way to add one more step into the code provided by Miguel to copy the rows that don't have at match from sheet 2 to a new sheet?