# Excel VBA or Formula to Match two worksheets then update values

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I did some research and found a issue similar to mine. Back in 2017 users @BruceWayne and @Miguel answered the scenario https://stackoverflow.com/a/42986167/14488103 but I had one extra scenario in place. Sheet 1 Static Data contains answers already.  Sheet 2 contains the 'to be updated data'. I still would like to keep data that doesn't need to be changed in Sheet 1 and allow the changes from Sheet 2 to occur. The VBA and Formula `=Index([Status Range],Match([customer ID]&[Case No.],[customer ID Range]&[Case No. Range],0)` work but doesn't allow me to retain the value that is listed that doesn't need to be updated. Here is an edited version of that scenario:

Sheet 1 Static data

`Customer Name | Customer ID | Case 1 | Case 2 | Case 3 | Case 4 | Case 5

------------------------------------------------------------------------
Customer A    | 111 | Upside   | Forecast | pipeline | Upside | Upside
Customer B    | 222 | Forecast | Upside   | Pipeline | Upside | Pipeline
Customer C    | 333 | Upside   | Upside   | Forecast | Upside | Upside
Customer D    | 444 | Pipeline | Forecast | Upside   | Upside | Upside
Customer E    | 555 | Forecast | Forecast | Upside   | Pipeline | Forecast`

---

Sheet 2 updated flex data

`Customer ID  | Use Case | Status

---------------------------------
111     |Case 1 | Forecast
222     |Case 1 | Upside
111     |Case 2 | Upside
333     |Case 3 | Pipeline
444     |Case 4 | Pipeline
222     |Case 4 | Forecast
555     |Case 5 | Pipeline`

---

Output sheet or Sheet 1

`Customer Name | Customer ID | Case 1 | Case 2 | Case 3 | Case 4 | Case 5

------------------------------------------------------------------------

Customer A    | 111| Forecast | Upside | Pipeline | Upside | Upside
Customer B    | 222| Upside  | Upside  | Pipeline | Forecast| Upside
Customer C    | 333| Upside  |  Upside | Pipeline | Upside  | Pipeline
Customer D    | 444| Pipeline | Forecast| Upside | Pipeline | Forecast
Customer E    | 555| Pipeline | Forecast | Upside | Forecast| PIPELINE`

---

Thanks for taking the time to help I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Hi AC, It sounds like you want to keep Sheet 1 the same as an 'Original' version and then have a dynamic report in a new sheet based of changes you make to sheet 2 - is that right? I think the answer you have found should enable you to do that so I'm not sure what issue you are facing?

Comment: Hey @maxhob17.  In Sheet 1 whatever that doesn't need to change should remain the same.  I ran the VBA Miquel did and it removed everything but the results listed in sheet 2.  I ran the formula that Bruce did and same.  It was like everything worked but sheet 1 (original) would only show the results just like the outcome in the previous question back in 2017 (results in line with the match and the rest just null/empty cells).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like the following. I included comments in the code for clarity, but write back with any questions.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim rngStatic As Range
    Dim rngNew As Range
    Dim oCaseMapper As Object
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim foundRange As Range
    Dim selectedCase As String
    
    'Store the range of the ID field from the static sheet
    'In this case, ID is column B
    Set rngStatic = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B" & _
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        
    'Store the range of the ID field from the static sheet
    'In this case, ID is column A
    Set rngNew = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:A" & _
        Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        
    'To keep things clean, I'm creating a dictionary that maps an
    'ID to a column offset. In the example, 'Case 1' is one column to
    'the left of the ID field, so the value will be 1. 'Case 2' is 2
    'columns to the left, so the value is 2, etc.
    Set oCaseMapper = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    oCaseMapper.Add "Case 1", 1
    oCaseMapper.Add "Case 2", 2
    oCaseMapper.Add "Case 3", 3
    oCaseMapper.Add "Case 4", 4
    oCaseMapper.Add "Case 5", 5
    
    'Now loop through all of the cells in the new range,
    'and push values to original sheet
    For Each cel In rngNew
        Set foundRange = rngStatic.Find(cel.Value2)
        If Not rngStatic.Find(cel.Value2) Is Nothing Then
            selectedCase = cel.Offset(, 1).Value2
            
            'Make sure that the case actually exists in our
            'dictionary, and is valid. Otherwise, generate some output
            If oCaseMapper.exists(selectedCase) Then
                foundRange.Offset(, oCaseMapper(selectedCase)).Value = cel.Offset(, 2).Value
            Else
                Debug.Print "Cant find " & selectedCase
            End If
        End If
    Next cel
    
End Sub
```

Comment: you are gdlk. Two quick questions that ends this. 1, if the data on my 'sheets' are shown in table format, do I change "Sheets" to "Tables" or remove the table aspect.  The other i didn't think until i looked at a similar report; on sheet 2 there is a 'add/remove' (action) column, therefore can i add a mapping that stats if the ids and cases match then do as the action column ask otherwise leave the result alone in sheet 1.   Thank you a million cause this works regardless (if you don't have time to address the other two questions). I wish it was more to give than just 'credit' :)

Comment: @ACKoop Regarding the first question, I'd actually have to run some tests to see what happens in table format. I don't know off the top of my head. For the second issue, definitely, you can respond to that additional value in Sheet 2. Within the `If oCaseMapper.exists...` conditional, you can embed another if statement. Within this, you can perform whatever action the corresponding data point requests. If you need additional help with that, post up some sample data and expected outcomes, and I'm sure we can assist.

Comment: Again thank you. I am going to take the data and make the changes on a normal excel sheet and then until i see how to reference the table cause it works so smooth once I take the data out of table mode.  Regarding the second question, its the same scenario just this its time add or remove but leave all other values alone. so if sheet 2 say the id match, the case match now the value is to be removed then remove otherwise leave it be based on a new 4th column in sheet 2.  Again should have looked over my request but I am happy 1 is resolved. Wish there was a messenger system, lol.